# Is it possible to format a memory stick, pen drive or disk using Java?

Tags: java, formatting, filesystems, disk-partitioning

I would like to create a multi-plattform utility to format / erase memory sticks, disks, etc.

Is it possible to do this in Java? Or do I need to call native methods for each operational system plattform?

Comment: What format do you want to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very system specific, there is no universal way to perform this.  Your options are

1. Create a JNI library to perform this using system calls
2. Write a wrapper class around utilities that perform this operation (for example, capture stdout and give inputs to stdin for an external process)
3. Use OS-specific techniques (as previously mentioned) to zero out devices
4. Use something like [fat32-lib](https://github.com/waldheinz/fat32-lib/) to manipulate specific file system types.

Comment: +1 for mentioning my fat32-lib ;-)

Comment: @Waldheinz your library looks great but I've not found any help or example on how to use it. Did you write anything about that?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly.  You will need to invoke a operating system specific program to do the actual work for you.

Answer (score 2):

On unix-like systems, you'd be able (only as root, most likely) to read the disk files `/dev/{h,s}d*` and write whatever byte sequence you want to them, including byte sequences that represent a, say, ext3 file system.

I don't know of any ext3 libraries in Java, though, so you might have to write it yourself.  Or a library for the file format you care about.

This is probably not what you want, though, but you can settle for it :-)