# Formatting Disk using Java

Tags: java, format, disk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to format a memory stick, pen drive or disk using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239350/is-it-possible-to-format-a-memory-stick-pen-drive-or-disk-using-java)

I need to format my pendrive into NTFS file system using a Java program. Can you please tell me how can I do this?
Thank you

Comment: The unit test would be funny :-)

Comment: Why do you think you have to use Java for this?

Answer (score 4):

Run native command line utilty of OS you are using. For example `format c:` on Windows :)

Use either `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` for this. 
Disk formating is a responsibility of file system that strongly depends on platform. Java is a cross-platform and I doubt it has (and even can or should have) such built-in functionality unless somebody already created library that wraps platform specific calls I mentioned and provides pure java API.

Comment: ok Alex..Can yuo please give me small sample code?

Answer (score 1):

you can not format directly. You will need to invoke a operating system specific program to do the actual work for you. [check this link this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441258/identify-file-system-format-of-a-disk-type-in-java-like-ntfs-fat16-32-or-ext)

Comment: +1 Under unix, as root, you can read/write the raw disk. If you know the exact format for an NTFS drive it could be done in theory, but it would take an obscene amount of effort.